# How can Javascript account for returning a 500?

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, http-status-code-500

I am using a login form to construct and send a URL (that'd be the "full url" written to storage in the script below) that should return a JSON object.

If the login is correct, the back-end sends me a JSON object with a validation key in it to validate if it cam back successfully. (like this:  [{"result":"VALID"}] )

If the login is incorrect, it only provides a 500 error.

Unfortunately, when it gets that 500 error, instead of booting them because the result isn't VALID, the script just gives up because there's no object to validate.

From the Front-End, how can I detect that I have received a 500 error and then trigger "bootThem()"?

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null); 
}

window.onload = function () {
    // get the url from storage.
    var fullURL = localStorage.getItem("fullURLStored")

    // if the URL is empty, boot them back to the login page.
    if(fullURL == " "){
        bootThem(); 
       }
       
    // send the URL to the server.
    readTextFile(fullURL, function (text) {
        
        var data = JSON.parse(text);

        if(data[0].result !== "VALID"){
            bootThem(); 
        } else{
            //do stuff
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {` <= That 200 section sure looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below fiddle I have simulated a 500 response from Mock API and handlinkg it:

```
  if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && ((rawFile.status === 200) || (rawFile.status === 500))) {
      console.log("fired");
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/vdegkyx2/8/

Comment: i think i need a way to differentiate between the 500 and the 200.  Currently, if there's a 500 or a 200, they both .log(''fired") to the console.  I need something like: if 500{"//boot them"}, if 200{proceed}. i tried to set that up as an if statement in your jsfiddel, but can't seem to get it to work:  <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/asutosh/vdegkyx2/8/embed/"></script> using google.com as a website i know should return successfully, it's just giving me "error code" in the log, instead of 200.

Comment: here's what i tried:
`
//should give 200!
    rawFile.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);//should give a 200.
 //should give 500!
     //rawFile.open("GET", "https://run.mocky.io/v3/977125b1-59ec-4bb2-b9e1-9c905160c105", true);  
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 200)) {
      console.log("200");
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 500)) {
      console.log("500");
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }`

Comment: For your referce below is the fiddle, i have two separate URL just to simulate success and failure scenario.  Go through the comments in the code to swicth between success (200) and failure (500)    https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/je5gy0hr/8/

Comment: Thanks @Austosh!  I was able to use this to help figure out what I needed!

Comment: @StephenHoydis please mark any of these answers which are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to Asutosh for the push in the right direction, I was able to adjust my function to boot the user if a 500 error was returned from the JSON call, and allow the user to pass through if there was not.

This was exactly what I needed to handle the 500 error coming back form the JSON:

```
function bootThem() {
   //execute code to reset session and return user to login page.
}

function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.addEventListener('error', () => {
    console.log("error code");
  });

  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 500)) {
        console.log("500");
        bootThem(); 
        callback(rawFile.responseText);
    } 
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 200)) {
        console.log("200");
        callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }

  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}


window.onload = function () {
    // get the url from storage.
    var fullURL = localStorage.getItem("fullURLStored")

    // if the URL is empty, boot them back to the login page.
    if(fullURL == " "){
        bootThem(); 
       }
       
    // send the URL to the server.
    readTextFile(fullURL, function (text) {
        
        var data = JSON.parse(text);

        if(data[0].result !== "VALID"){
            bootThem(); 
        } else{
            //do stuff
        }
    }); 
}
```